# No JSON object could be decoded, JvectorMap Converter

Tags: python, json, windows, shapefile, jvectormap

Scenario is,

Im new to python and trying to generate jvectorMap using `Converter.py` plugin provided by `jVectorMap`,

I have installed OSGEO4W (Desktop INSTALL) on Windows 7 64bit. Python 2.7,GDAL 2.1.0 and Shapely is also installed under OSGEO4W.

I download shapefile

```
ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp
```

I placed this shape file in converter.py directory, then I opened OSGEO4W shell and navigates to converter.py directory and run following command to generate Russia map for learning conversion of maps.

```
python  converter.py ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp test-map.js --width 400 --where "ISO_3166_2 = 'RU-' and code_hasc!='' --country_name_index 12 --country_code_index 18 --minimal_area 4000000 --buffer_distance -0.5 --simplify_tolerance 10000 --longitude0 54.8270 --name russia
```

I have taken this command from this post How to generate a new map for jvectormap jquery plugin? but I faced error JSON object Decode, have a look on below image
[image]

Help me to solve my problem ,As I have stated im new to python and jvector Maps

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that the passed in arguments cannot be converted to JSON by the script due to a missing double quote at the end of your `--where`. It should probably be:

```
--where "ISO_3166_2 = 'RU-' and code_hasc!=''"
```

**EDIT**:

Turns out it's a larger issue. If you look at the source code for [converter.py](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap/blob/master/converter/converter.py), you'll find this:

```
args = {}
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
  paramsJson = open(sys.argv[1], 'r').read()
else:
  paramsJson = sys.stdin.read()
paramsJson = json.loads(paramsJson)
```

So, it looks like this script cannot be called this way. It's either expecting a file with this JSON in it, or for the params to be passed through stdin. The [documentation](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/gis-converter/) seems to agree with this.

Comment: I printed out json before decoded it prints special characters

Comment: in documentations, they used proccessor.py ,not converter.py , im confused

Comment: The documentation is likely not up-to-date. But, the source code tells you how this works.

Comment: im new to python, I have to use it for jvectormaps converter, have you done it before?